# MySQL query was working before, now it isn't?

Tags: mysql

I'm having an odd problem, and I don't have the slightest idea of why it isn't working.
I have the following query that I constructed:

```
SELECT servers.id, servers.name, servers.address, servers.port, servers.up, servers.down, servers.genre, servers.score, servers.version, servers.country, ROUND( AVG( reviews.average ) , 0 ) AS review
FROM servers
INNER JOIN reviews ON servers.id = reviews.server
ORDER BY servers.score DESC
```

This query was working fine a few weeks ago. It is meant to get many fields from the "servers" table, and the average field from the "reviews" table where the server in the "reviews" table is the same as the id in the "servers" table.

Like I said, this query was working fine before. Yesterday I noticed that a vital part of my site wasn't working, and I figured out that this query is failing.

I've confirmed that is returning exactly 1 row (when, at the moment, it should be returning 4, because there are 4 entries in the "servers" table.)
This is what phpMyAdmin gives me when I execute that query:

```
id    name  address  port   up    down  genre   score   version  country   review
NULL  NULL  NULL     NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL       NULL
```

Could anybody enlighten me? I've come here as a last resort, because I am stuck.

Comment: have you checked the table ? maybe some thing is wrong in the back end (my advice use workbench to check if your tables are still there)

Comment: You may want to do some `select * from servers` queries and see if you are missing data. You may have fallen victim to a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: I'm 100% certain that there is no data missing, and I'm really sure I eliminated all chance of SQL injection (I clean user input and use prepared statements). `SELECT * FROM servers` gives me the expected number of rows, while this query is giving me 1, with all fields NULL.

Comment: Good work on protecting your data. If you are getting rows from the servers table I would suggest you check the reviews table, or change the `inner join` to a `left outer join`.

Comment: @Mike Purcell Hmm, I think I figured out the issue, but I don't have a solution: I think if there isn't a "review" that corresponds to a server, it wont work (in this case, the reviews table is empty) How can I make the query work so that if there is no review, it will return NULL for the review? You could post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, try changing the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which will return servers, regardless if there is a matched row in the review table or not. Also, you didn't post your schema, but double check the `reviews.server` column in the reviews table, it may be `server_id` instead. Another issue, you are doing an `AVG` which is a grouped calculation, but you have no `GROUP BY` clause, so I would suggest adding it, so your full query should look like:

```
SELECT servers.id, servers.name, servers.address, servers.port, servers.up, servers.down, servers.genre, servers.score, servers.version, servers.country, ROUND( AVG( reviews.average ) , 0 ) AS review
FROM servers
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON servers.id = reviews.server # might be reviews.server_id
GROUP BY reviews.server
ORDER BY servers.score DESC
```

More info about GROUP BY [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html).

**-- Update --**

```
SELECT servers.id, servers.name, servers.address, servers.port, servers.up, servers.down, servers.genre, servers.score, servers.version, servers.country, IFNULL(ROUND(AVG(reviews.average)), 0) AS review
FROM servers
LEFT OUTER JOIN reviews ON servers.id = reviews.server
GROUP BY servers.id
ORDER BY servers.score DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, it is now working as expected. I'm going to have to go do some research now. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey, Mike, I'm back because I'm having issues with this solution, sadly. In my testing scenario, I have 2 rows in the "servers" table, and 0 rows in the "reviews" table. When I use that query, I only get 1 result from the servers table. I'm not sure why, exactly. Could you try to help me out?

Comment: The query is doing a group by, do the server rows have different ids? If not then the `group by` will result in a single row.

Comment: They do infact have different ids. (One is 6, and the other is 102). It always returns the id=6 row. Oddly enough, if I make the first row's id 102, and the second row's id 6 (so, switching them around), it will return the id=102 row (originally the id=6 row)

Comment: Try the query without the `group by` and without the `round(avg())` and see if you get back both rows. Also, if you could post the schema of both tables and the query you are trying that would help as well.

Comment: Removing the AVG and group by works, but I need that AVG. I'll update the question with the schemas and query.

Comment: Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Not sure why the `round` is not returning all the rows you are expecting, but I updated with a query you can try using `ifnull`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no good. Same results. I have NO idea why it wouldn't be working. :|

Comment: My bad, I had the `GROUP BY` wrong, it should be `GROUP BY servers.id` instead of `GROUP BY reviews.server`. The reason is because servers is the primary table where as reviews table is auxillary. I updated my update with correct `GROUP BY` syntax.

Comment: Alright it's working for real now. thank you SO much. Sorry for being so helpless; I'm not the best at this kindof thing. The important thing is: it works and I'm learning.

Comment: No worries, it's part of the process. Good luck.